# C++ List::insert compilation error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use **list::insert** to insert an object into a list. I'm encountering a couples of trouble and compilation errors while doing so. This is my function:

```
class Gui {
    private:
        std::vector<const Widget*> NoButtons;
        std::list<const AbstractButton*> Buttons;
    public:
        void insert(Widget* p){
            if(!p)
                throw "NoInsert";
            else
                NoButtons.vector::push_back(p);
        }

        void insert(unsigned int i, PushButton& pb){
            std::list<const AbstractButton*>::const_iterator cit = Buttons.begin();

            for(int k=0; k < i; k++)
                {
                    if(cit == Buttons.end())
                        throw "NoInsert";
                    else
                        cit++;
                }

            Buttons.list::insert(cit, &pb); 
        }
```

The **second** `insert` function has to insert a `PushButton` item (which is a derived class of `AbstractButton`) to the buttons list in a specific position, given by the `unsigned int` parameter. I'm a newbie in C++ programming and i really like to understand how can i achieve this result in the best possible way. Also, i don't know what kind of scoping i need to use in order to avoid conflicts between the declared `insert` functions and the `insert` functions already available in `vector` and `list` classes.

I get this kind of error:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::list<const AbstractButton*>::insert(std::list<const AbstractButton*>::const_iterator&, PushButton*)'
```

Comment: For future reference, when you get a compilation error, post the entire error here so that we can better help you.

Comment: Try Buttons.insert(cit, &pb); instead of Buttons.list::insert(cit, &pb); and NoButtons.push_back(p); instead of NoButtons.vector::push_back(p);

Comment: `std::vector<const Widget*>` I want to meet the first person who wrote this line of sh*t. appearently, many beginners try to imitiate this nonsense. this is maybe the #20 post I see with `Vector<T*>`

Comment: `NoButtons.vector::`, `Buttons.list` You should just say `NoButtons.` and `Buttons.`, no need to try and access the container.

Comment: @DavidHaim: There's nothing inherently wrong with `vector<T*>`.

Comment: It looks like you started protecting against scope conflicts before you knew that there were any. There aren't.

Comment: @AndyG give me one reason to store a pointer to widget instead of a widget please.

Comment: @David: Sadly, many GUI frameworks insist upon giving you pointers to dynamically allocated widget "handles" and there's not much you can do about that. Granted, it makes some sense when you can't guarantee the availability or use of move semantics.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Oftentimes for reference sharing, especially when the contents of the vector may be reordered. Of course lifetime management has to be well established.

Comment: @AndyG reference sharing = std::shared_ptr, or maybe you wnat to insist write C++98 code.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You can't use `std::shared_ptr` on something that doesn't support it. Like many GUI frameworks. Have you used a GUI framework?

Comment: @PreferenceBean put costume deleter , voila. if the GUI framwork doesn't give you a proper delting function-> you're not having a C++ framework

Comment: @DavidHaim: Agreed, but `vector<T*>` is the same thing as `vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>` in my eyes. Point is, memory ownership must be well established. Also, not everything supports C++11 yet.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Out here in the real world we have to deal with reality, not fantasy scenarios. Why should all of Gtk, Qt, wxWidgets and so on be fundamentally redesigned just because a vector of widgets _can_ now be done differently? And just because David says so? Those frameworks have worked excellently for years.

Comment: I have no complains for QT and wxWidgets. I just don't find the line `vector<Widget*>` ok when you can use vector+smart pointers where you can set costume deleter/allocator.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You're not listening. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `NoButtons.vector::` to access the member functions of `std::vector<const Widget*>`. That is incorrect syntax, as the compiler probably tells you. You can simply use `NoButtons.`. Instead of

```
NoButtons.vector::push_back(p);
```

use

```
NoButtons.push_back(p);
```

You may use

```
NoButtons.vector<const Widget*>::push_back(p);
```

but it is not necessary to use the longer syntactic form.

```
NoButtons.vector::push_back(p);
```

is syntactically incorrect since `vector` is not a type. `vector<const Widget*>` is a type.

Similarly, instead of

```
Buttons.list::insert(cit, &pb);
```

use

```
Buttons.insert(cit, &pb);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's invalid? I can believe that it would be (without a template param list) but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PreferenceBean, yes, that is invalid.

Comment: I already tried, and it gives me the error:

[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::list<const AbstractButton*>::insert(std::list<const AbstractButton*>::const_iterator&, PushButton*)'

Comment: @Mastarius: That overload is only available since C++11. Are you using C++11?

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be correct at compile time when removing the incorrect scoping operators as mentioned by R Sahu. But also i need to use iterator instead of const_iterator even though i'm not using iterators directly to modify members, that still gives me compilation errors. I have no clue about this, so i'd like to hear your comments about it.

```
void insert(unsigned int i, PushButton& pb){
        std::list<const AbstractButton*>::iterator cit = Buttons.begin();

        for(int k=0; k < i; k++)
            {
                if(cit == Buttons.end())
                    throw "NoInsert";
                else
                    cit++;
            }

        cit++;
        Buttons.insert(cit, &pb);

    }
```

I will do some tests at runtime to see if it's working properly. 
Thanks for your help